# Copying UDP traffic from a bound port

Tags: networking

I have two applications that both bind to the same port to receive UDP traffic. I am able to change the listen port of one of the programs but not the other. I need both to be able to see the traffic.

I have tried using socat for this but have been unable to figure out how to get it to send a copy of the traffic to a different port without interfering with the program bound to the original port.

Comment: Ports are exclusive to a single process, and you cannot share a port between two processes. The process that owns the port could also send anything received to a different process. You could modify one process to send to the other, or you could create a new, separate process to send to both of the existing processes.

Comment: I am unable to modify the sending processes or one of the receiving processes to do so.

Answer (score 0):

A few tricks come to mind, but when you are not able to change both receiving ports or the target port of the sender, you will need to use iptables to modify the port of the incoming packets. On that port Socat with sniffing (option -r) to a pipe and another Socat instance could solve your problem.